Help needed in understanding tension force from SL Loney's book, "THE ELEMENTS OF STATICS AND DYNAMICS"
I was reading a book "THE ELEMENTS OF STATICS AND DYNAMICS" by SL Loney.
On page number 4 there is a section about "Tension." The paragraph went on as follows:

If we tie one end of a string to any
point of a body and pull at the other end of the string, we exert a force on the body ; such a force, exerted by means of a string or rod, is called a tension.
If the string be light [i.e. one whose weight is so small that it may be neglected] the force exerted by the string is the same throughout its length.
For example, if a weight W be
supported by means of a light
string passing over the smooth
edge of a table it is found that the same force must be applied to the string whatever be the point, A, B, or C of the string at which the force is applied.
Now the force at A required to support the weight is the same in each case ; hence it is clear that the effect at A is the same whatever be the point of the string to which the tension is applied and that the tension of the string is therefore the same throughout its length.

Again, if the weight W be supported by a light string passing round a smooth peg A, it is found that the same force must be exerted at the other end of the string whatever be the direction (AB, AC, or AD) in which the string is pulled and that this force is equal to the weight W. [These forces may be measured by attaching the free end of the string to a spring-balance.] Hence the tension of a light string passing round a smooth peg is the same throughout its length.



However, there are a few things I am not getting in this text.

First of all, I dont know how they claim that, "Now the force at A required to support the weight is the same in each case ; hence it is clear that the effect at A is the same whatever be the point of the string to which the tension is applied and that the tension of the string is therefore the same throughout its length."

[I understand the statements prior to this:
"...if a weight W be
supported by means of a light
string passing over the smooth
edge of a table it is found that the same force must be applied to the string whatever be the point, A, B, or C of the string at which the force is applied"
is made solely through an experimental validation/verification.]
But, this statement, starts with, the phrase, " the force at A required to support the weight is the same in each case,..." but my question is, "What cases are they referring to?" If we apply the force at the point B then at the point A we're not applying any force, so why should there be a force at A?
From a practical standpoint, I think if the force is applied at the point B (as shown in the figure 1) then the force is also felt at the point A and probably due to which they say that it seems as if we're applying the force that we applied at the point B at the point A instead of B, or in other words, we may think that we're applying a force at the point A (although we're actually applying the force at B) instead of B, as it won't change anything. What they try to mean is maybe that the change in point of application of force in the string does not lead to any change in the phyiscal situation.
Next, I tried to find the reason why they say that the effect of the weight W is same at A irrespective of whichever the point of application of the tension may be.
I see it in the following way:
Whenever such an arrangement of a weight W supported by a weightless string through the smooth edge of a table is given to us, it seems that at whatever the point in the string we shift our focus to, the effect of the weight W is same and so the force at that point is same as all other points. But the force applied through a string or a rod is called tension and thus, the tension of the string is same at all points.
In fact, the above (written in bold) is what I summarized reading the whole text.
Are my interpretations correct and valid? Or have I gone wrong somewhere?

The force of gravity on W is the weight of W. To hold W up, we have to pull upward with a force equal to the weight. Let us call this F. We do this with a string. So at A, we pull with a force equal to F.
Next we add to the string, extending it to D or C or B. We pull on the string. So D pulls on A pulls on W. We have to pull on D with a force equal to F, so that D pulls on A that hard. Which makes A pull on W that hard.
This is why we say the tension is the same throughout the string.

You may wonder why the string has to be light. Suppose you used a heavy chain for the same purpose, where is link pulls on the next and each link weighs something. Call the weight of a link L.
The first link would have to pull upward with force F to hold up W. The second link has to hold up W plus the first link. So it pulls upward with force F+L. The next link has to hold up W plus 2 links. So the force is W+2L. And so on.
This makes problems more complicated without adding any new physics concepts. So in an introductory course, these problems always use a very light string. This allows you to focus on the important ideas. You will see a heavy string in more advanced problems.

Your explanation in the first 3 paragraphs of your answer basically works for both the cases, viz. (i) when the string is passed over the smooth edge of a table, (ii) when its passed round a smooth peg A, isn't it?

Yes, that is right.

In a massless string at rest, the way to understand that the tension must be same throughout is by Newton's second law: if at any point/infinitesimal element of the string there was a tension gradient, then across that small element there would be a net force, causing that part of string to accelerate. However, since the element is massless, the acceleration would be infinite implying there can be no change in tension across it i.e. tension is constant throughout the string. This also means that massive strings can have uneven tension along there length when loaded or accelerated.
The language of the textbook seems a bit outdated to me. What the author meant is precisely as you inferred: the tension at $A$ as determined by the unchanging weight at equilibrium, is exactly matched by that anywhere else 'behind' it (at $B$,$C$ etc.) or for that matter at any point on the string.

In this sort of example the massless string can have two functions:

transmit a force from one point to another point, and

change the direction of a force


In your diagram, the upward force due to the string on object $W$ has the same magnitude as the force on points $B, \, C$ and $D$ due to the string but they are in different directions.
As the string is assumed massless (much less mass than any other mass in the system) the net force on any section of the string must be zero (much less than any other force in the system), otherwise it would have an infinite (extremely large) acceleration.
T he tension forces in the string are the same.
